# Altium: Components don't move with their room

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I have a design with several rooms in it. I did a part of the routing and I don't know what I did, but now when I move a room, the components don't move with it.

I found something in the [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Obj-Room((Room))_AD):

> Once component(s) have been assigned to a room, they move when the room is moved. To move a room without moving the components, temporarily disable the associated Room Definition rule - either in the PCB Rules and Constraints Editor dialog or in the PCB Inspector panel (with the room in question selected in the workspace).

But I wasn't successful with this help...

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a clik on the  menu "Design / Import changes", components move again with the room.

I don't know why.

Comment: You should add a little more detail into this answer if you want it to be helpful

Comment: I did my best..

Answer (score 1):

Rules->Placement->Room Definition->Make sure rooms are enabled.